# MSDN App tutorial for creating a windows application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to learn how to create a windows application but I get this error while writing the code.

[szWindowClass undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XiWk.png)

Here is the site for the tutorial.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

here is the code

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>


//winMain function
//function starting point
int CALLBACK WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    //handles messages
    LRESULT CALLBACK winproc(
        _In_ HWND   hwnd,
        _In_ UINT   uMsg,
        _In_ WPARAM wParam,
        _In_ LPARAM lParam
    );

    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = winproc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed"),
            _T("Win32 guided tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("win_proj1_test");
    static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Win32 Guided Tour Application");

    // The parameters to CreateWindow explained:  
    // szWindowClass: the name of the application  
    // szTitle: the text that appears in the title bar  
    // WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW: the type of window to create  
    // CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT: initial position (x, y)  
    // 500, 100: initial size (width, length)  
    // NULL: the parent of this window  
    // NULL: this application does not have a menu bar  
    // hInstance: the first parameter from WinMain  
    // NULL: not used in this application  
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        500, 100,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("Win32 Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:  
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow  
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain  
    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking CreateWindow before the definition of szWindowClass:

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindow(
    szWindowClass,
```

Move this line:

```
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("win_proj1_test");
```

To the very top of the file. Right above WinMain.